# UniqueConstraint Django unique together

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True,
    )
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(
        'Avatar',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Profile'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'


class Avatar(CreatedByModel):

    avatar = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name='Avatar',
        upload_to=UploadTo(prefix='avatars'),
        blank=True,
    )
    default = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Default avatar?',
        default=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Avatar'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Avatars'
```

I need to create UniqueConstraint in Profile model based on a default in Avatar model, I tried to make this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
...

class Meta:
    constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'avatar'],
                condition=Q(avatar__default=False),
                name='unique_id_avatar_default',
            ),
        ]
```

But got an error: Django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query

Are there any other ways to do what I want?

**UPDATE**

Full Traceback, as i understand there is problem in `avatar__default`:

```
Applying accounts.0035_auto_20210701_1755...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 808, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_constraint(model, self.constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 360, in add_constraint
    sql = constraint.create_sql(model, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/constraints.py", line 117, in create_sql
    condition = self._get_condition_sql(model, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/constraints.py", line 102, in _get_condition_sql
    where = query.build_where(self.condition)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1364, in build_where
    return self.build_filter(filter_expr, allow_joins=False)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1237, in build_filter
    return self._add_q(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1264, in build_filter
    raise FieldError("Joined field references are not permitted in this query")
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query
```

Comment: Would it help to use `avatar_id` in the constraint rather than `avatar`?

Comment: Can you provide the *full* traceback?

Comment: You can not reference to a field of another table, a `CHECK` and `UNIQUE` constraint spans over *one* table, not multiple ones.